# Creating module with routing using CLI and linking it with main route configuration

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

When creating module using command:

```
ng g m dashboard --routing
```

it creates module with appriopriate routing configuration for this module. Is it possible for the Angular CLI to link the main route with this sub-route automatically or do I always need to edit main route configuration by myself?

Comment: Angular and the CLI don't know where in your main app's routes you actually want that module to live, so you have to do that yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually when you generate app using `ng new` with `--routing`parameter it will always create the main routing configuration in the same way in `app-routing.module.ts` so angular actually could detect it and link sub-routing with main routing.

Answer (score 0):

add parameter `--module` in your command like following:

`ng g m dashboard --routing --module app` (assuming your target module name is app)